# HttpClient Poor Performance

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.8

When I create a new `HttpClient` object on every request, I am getting
a response very quickly.

I know that we should not create a new `HttpClient` on each request, hence I started using `HttpClient` from `HttpClientFactory` and inject `HttpClient` on each request but surprisingly performance is very bad.

**Global.asax**

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Populate(services);

var autofacContainer = builder.Build();
```

**Sample.asmx**

Approach 1: ResponseTime was 1.5 Second

```
var client_ = DependencyInjector.Provider.RequestLifetime.Resolve<HttpClient>();;//Inject
using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
            {
var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Approach 2: ResponseTime was .5 Second

```
var client_ = new HttpClient();
using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
            {
var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Using .Netframework 4.8. Any suggestion?

Comment: When you profiled the code, which line took the extra time? It's quite possible that your DI call is the slow part. *(It's also [an anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/): wherever possible, dependencies should be injected into the controller or method, not explicitly fetched from a service locator.)*

Comment: SendAsync takes time. Since I was using asp.net old ASMX I don't have choice to inject dependency from constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I started moving my code in blank project one by one and I found root cause. Just sharing in case someone face similar issue.

I was using `SumoLogic.Logging.Serilog` sink to send log data in Sumo Logic and seems issue with my implementation or this package, but after removing below line of code from `Program.cs` it was working much better

```
loggerConfig.WriteTo.SumoLogic(endpointUrl: new Uri(sumoLogicUri));
```

To fix issue, I have changed extension method as suggested in [docs](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-net-appenders/blob/main/docs/sumologic.logging.serilog.md)

```
    loggerConfig.WriteTo.BufferedSumoLogic(endpointUrl: new Uri(sumoLogicUri));
```